# Need help for expanding Guava with client side GWT emulation

Tags: java, gwt, guava

I have an open pull request for Guava here: https://github.com/google/guava/pull/2112. Problem is, since guava introduced some more unittests in Guava-GWT, some tests fail since there is no client-side emulation for the class ThreadLocalBuffers that I introduced. I tried to fix this, but GWT client side emulation is poorly documented and I have no idea why my fix does not work: https://github.com/berndhopp/guava/commit/36bc7be81cc48325a7ac52ad599c4e58e7a50af8. Any help appreciated.

Regards
Bernd

Comment: "I have no idea why my fix does not work" What is the specific problem? How do you reproduce this problem?

Comment: This might be better suited for a mailing list than a StackOverflow question - also consider IRC or the gitter channels for gwt and guava.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a `base.super.com.google.common.io` folder instead of a `base/super/com/google/common/io` hierarchy.